# How to retrieve the last 4 characters from a mysql database field?

Tags: php, mysql, substr

In order to be able to simulate substr from PHP and mysql, I want to do something like

```
select * from table where last_four_chars(field) = '.png'
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

[The docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) have an example directly relevant to this.

```
select * from table where SUBSTRING(field, -4) = '.png'
```

Answer (score 19):

With RIGHT function :

```
SELECT RIGHT('abcdefg', 3);
-- efg
```

You can achieve the same result with SUBSTRING :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('abcdefg', -3);
-- efg
```

Answer (score 5):

This Fast query:

```
Select * from table where picName like '%.png'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE SUBSTRING( field, -4 ) = '.png'
```