# New variable with last 3 numbers from id

Tags: php

I got in my DB over 3.000.000 lines and i need last 3 numbers from table ID.
For example:

```
$id = "123456";  (instead of this number will be a mysql query)
$newid = "456";  (this is what i need)
```

How should i do this?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: have a look on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467336/how-to-retrieve-the-last-4-characters-from-a-mysql-database-field

Comment: Read the manual: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Just take the remainder of a division by 1000: `$newid = $id % 1000;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ID_COLUM_NAME,-3,3) as Id from TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now i got another problem. String for id=1 is 1, but i need to be 001. Any ideas?

Comment: you want to store as 001 in db or something else